# how to check which product we are using in our account in netsuite

Tags: netsuite

I need check which product we are using . Fpr example oneworld or base product etc.There are so many products in netsuite. Where I have check which product am using .
Please answer me.

Answer (score 3):

If I'm not mistaken, only OneWorld has subsidiaries.  So you could check Setup > Company > Subsidiaries.  If you have that option and can add subsidiaries, you should be on OneWorld.  Alternatively, you can call Netsuite (1-866-522-1508), and they can tell you definitively.